# Were there any famous Asian philosophers who were also mathematicians?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

New here, had a question: Were there any famous Asian philosophers who were also mathematicians? Happy Xmas!

Comment: See also [Hao Wang (1921 - 1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hao_Wang_(academic)) : [From Mathematics to Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=TLM9AAAAIAAJ) (1974) and [Beyond Analytic Philosophy: Doing Justice to What We Know](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/beyond-analytic-philosophy) (1985).

Answer (score 2):

Kātyāyana, Brahmagupta, Jing Fang and many other from India, China and other regions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_mathematicians
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_mathematicians

At that time there wasn't a clear cut between disciplines.

Babylonia and Egypt also had mathematicians but we don't know their names.

Answer (score 1):

Most of famous mathematicians/astronomers of the Muslim countries were also philosophers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_in_the_medieval_Islamic_world

Comment: To be honest, I cannot think of a single author in the mediaeval Islamic world who wrote important works both on mathematics and on falsafa. The important mathematicians (al-Khwarazmi, al-Biruni, al-Khayyami) all steered well clear of philosophy.

Comment: There were some but they are much newer than the first Indians, Chinese and Greeks. And they are known not because of their own creations but because they brought the knowledge of Chinese and Indians to Europe.

Comment: @skan. India yes, China no.